# What word means "an event that can occur without an appointment/schedule"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm trying my best to describe an event people don't need to make an appointment for ahead of time or schedule. It should sound more formal than "drop-in".

An example usage:

> A doctor's appointment must be arranged ahead of time whereas this event is _______.

Comment: Maybe you still need an appointment, but that appointment can be created on-the-spot/fly.

Comment: What about a *flexible* event, or perhaps an *unscheduled* event ?  In some cases "open" works: Coach has an open door policy.  Do you essentially mean *"no appointment necessary"* but you want that in a single word?

Comment: @Kanne I would certainly have developed impromptu as an answer but you have priority.

Comment: @KannE Love the dog comment! Happy New Year to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To amplify an earlier comment:

> *impromptu* = done or said without earlier planning or preparation
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impromptu)

Made up adjectival examples:

"We are just heading for an impromptu meeting. Care to join us?"

"The meal was delicious even though it was impromptu."

The word may also be used as an adverb

> without preparation or planning
>
> "Roy came up and just started speaking impromptu"
>
> [Oxford learners](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/impromptu_1)

It comes from:

> *impromptu* (adv.) 1660s, from French *impromptu* (1650s), from Latin *in promptu* "in readiness", from assimilated form of in- "into, in, on, upon" (from PIE root *en "in") + *promptu*, ablative of *promptus* "ready, prepared";
>
> [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/impromptu)

Because of its long usage and its foreign flavour, the word has the desired more formal feel than "drop-in".